# Need help in Updating All the Product Names of a Opportunity onto a text field via trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement that on the case object I have a field **"Related Opportunity"** which has lookup to opportunity. Now I need to create one more field **"Related Product"** which shows the list of all the **Product Names(i.e OpportunityLineItems)** of the attached Opportunity. We do not have the option to create a lookup field on **"OpportunityLineItems"** Object. So I thought to first create a text field on opportunity and populate the value of all the products via trigger in this field. Then created a formula field on Case to get the value of this field. But my trigger is not updating the values of Product in opportunity. Below is the trigger code.

```
Trigger UpdateProdOnOpportunity on OpportunityLineItem(after insert, after update) 
{
    Set<Id> parentIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem R : trigger.new)
    {
        parentIdSet.add(R.Opportunity.Id);
        system.debug('---parentIdSet---'+parentIdSet);  //Here I am getting NULL value
    }

    Map<Id,Opportunity> AllOppRecords = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([Select Product_Details__c from Opportunity  where id in :parentIdSet]);

    for(OpportunityLineItem OLI : trigger.new)
    {
        if(AllOppRecords.size() > 0 && AllOppRecords.containsKey(OLI.Opportunity.id ))
        {
            if(AllOppRecords.get(OLI.Opportunity.Id).Product_Details__c == null || AllOppRecords.get(OLI.Opportunity.Id ).Product_Details__c == '')
            {
               AllOppRecords.get(OLI.Opportunity.Id ).Product_Details__c = OLI.Product2.Name;
            }
            else
            {
               AllOppRecords.get(OLI.Opportunity.Id ).Product_Details__c = AllOppRecords.get(OLI.Opportunity.Id ).Product_Details__c + ';' + OLI.Product2.Name;
            }
          }
     }
     update AllOppRecords.values();
}
```

**Below is the debug log**

```
Log 
35.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
01:15:45.954 (954904197)|EXECUTION_STARTED
01:15:45.954 (954960175)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q190000004MF1|UpdateProdOnOpportunity on OpportunityLineItem trigger event AfterInsert for [00k19000003avhf]
01:15:45.955 (955080140)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
01:15:45.956 (956224573)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
01:15:45.956 (956333165)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
01:15:45.956 (956380303)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
01:15:45.956 (956430284)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
01:15:45.956 (956477471)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
01:15:45.956 (956550436)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
01:15:45.956 (956607864)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:1
01:15:45.956 (956880347)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
01:15:45.956 (956911174)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|UpdateProdOnOpportunity|true|false
01:15:45.957 (957011053)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x2918a99f
01:15:45.957 (957143315)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
01:15:45.957 (957166616)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|UpdateProdOnOpportunity|true|false
01:15:45.957 (957209613)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x2918a99f
01:15:45.957 (957225957)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
01:15:45.957 (957233057)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
01:15:45.957 (957253141)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:4
01:15:45.957 (957437428)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
01:15:45.957 (957496736)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
01:15:45.957 (957522183)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
01:15:45.957 (957696596)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[3]|this.parentIdSet|{"s":1,"v":[]}|0x2918a99f
01:15:45.958 (958550447)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:5
01:15:45.958 (958648476)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[5]|R|OpportunityLineItem|true|false
01:15:46.005 (1005384995)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[5]|R|{"LastModifiedDate":"2015-10-28T07:15:44.000Z","PL_Part_Total_Bits__ (1 more) ...":"512M","TAM_Unit_Quantity__c":3,"ListPrice":2.35,"PL_Product_Technolog (4 more) ...":"PARALLEL","PL_Product_Total_Bit (4 more) ...":"512M","CreatedById":"0051300000BzkUrAAJ","HasSchedule":false,"OpportunityId":"00619000003S2pOAAS","Actual_Cust_Qual_Dat (4 more) ...":"2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z","IsDeleted":false,"Product_Family__c":"NOR FLASH","ProductCode":"000000000000131702","PL_Product_Group_alg (3 more) ...":"MLC 512M X16 LBGA","Share_of_Market__c":767,"Subtotal":54.05,"Quantity":23.00,"Customer_Part_Number (3 more) ...":"35232","PL_Product_Code_alg_ (2 more) ...":"000000000000131702","HasQuantitySchedule":false,"SystemModstamp":"2015-10-28T07:15:44.000Z","UnitPrice":2.35,"Apttus_Approval__App (15 more) ...":"None","Product2Id":"01t30000002I8ozAAC","TAM_Revenue__c":2.35,"PricebookEntryId":"01u1300000lxQgsAAE","TotalPrice":54.05,"CreatedDate":"2015-10-28T07:15:44.000Z","PL_Product_Family_c_ (2 more) ...":"NOR FLASH","Proj_Qual_Date__c":"2015-10-29T00:00:00.000Z","Id":"00k19000003avhfAAA","PL_Design_ID_Alg__c":"QKKP","HasRevenueSchedule":false,"LastModifiedById":"0051300000BzkUrAAJ"}|0x3d66c41c
01:15:46.005 (1005468594)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[6]
01:15:46.005 (1005478434)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[7]
01:15:46.005 (1005741749)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.005 (1005788180)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
01:15:46.005 (1005803900)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:17
01:15:46.005 (1005989595)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:6
01:15:46.006 (1006054243)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:23
01:15:46.006 (1006130121)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|---parentIdSet---{null}
01:15:46.006 (1006202249)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:5
01:15:46.006 (1006255797)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[5]|R|null|
01:15:46.006 (1006268284)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[11]
01:15:46.006 (1006288471)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.006 (1006301004)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:62
01:15:46.006 (1006321388)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.006 (1006347939)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:7
01:15:46.006 (1006939213)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[11]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Product_Details__c FROM Opportunity WHERE id = :tmpVar1
01:15:46.014 (1014772891)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[11]|Rows:0
01:15:46.014 (1014824355)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.014 (1014862609)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:0
01:15:46.015 (1015005149)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.015 (1015215760)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[11]|this.AllOppRecords|{"s":1,"v":{}}|0x2918a99f
01:15:46.015 (1015390370)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:5
01:15:46.015 (1015450788)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[13]|OLI|OpportunityLineItem|true|false
01:15:46.016 (1016438028)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[13]|OLI|{"LastModifiedDate":"2015-10-28T07:15:44.000Z","PL_Part_Total_Bits__ (1 more) ...":"512M","TAM_Unit_Quantity__c":3,"ListPrice":2.35,"PL_Product_Technolog (4 more) ...":"PARALLEL","PL_Product_Total_Bit (4 more) ...":"512M","CreatedById":"0051300000BzkUrAAJ","HasSchedule":false,"OpportunityId":"00619000003S2pOAAS","Actual_Cust_Qual_Dat (4 more) ...":"2015-10-31T00:00:00.000Z","IsDeleted":false,"Product_Family__c":"NOR FLASH","ProductCode":"000000000000131702","PL_Product_Group_alg (3 more) ...":"MLC 512M X16 LBGA","Share_of_Market__c":767,"Subtotal":54.05,"Quantity":23.00,"Customer_Part_Number (3 more) ...":"35232","PL_Product_Code_alg_ (2 more) ...":"000000000000131702","HasQuantitySchedule":false,"SystemModstamp":"2015-10-28T07:15:44.000Z","UnitPrice":2.35,"Apttus_Approval__App (15 more) ...":"None","Product2Id":"01t30000002I8ozAAC","TAM_Revenue__c":2.35,"PricebookEntryId":"01u1300000lxQgsAAE","TotalPrice":54.05,"CreatedDate":"2015-10-28T07:15:44.000Z","PL_Product_Family_c_ (2 more) ...":"NOR FLASH","Proj_Qual_Date__c":"2015-10-29T00:00:00.000Z","Id":"00k19000003avhfAAA","PL_Design_ID_Alg__c":"QKKP","HasRevenueSchedule":false,"LastModifiedById":"0051300000BzkUrAAJ"}|0x3d66c41c
01:15:46.016 (1016473239)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
01:15:46.016 (1016611318)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
01:15:46.016 (1016654149)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:5
01:15:46.016 (1016694013)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[13]|OLI|null|
01:15:46.016 (1016705033)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[27]
01:15:46.016 (1016807062)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.016 (1016830059)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[27]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.017 (1017112689)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
01:15:46.017 (1017165056)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
01:15:46.017 (1017165056)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
```

Please help me with the trigger code. Or let me know if there is some other approach which I can take to fulfill the requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
R.Opportunity.Id
OLI.Opportunity.Id
```

use:

```
R.OpportunityId
OLI.OpportunityId
```

because in triggers only the immediate fields of the object are populated so relationship fields like Opportunity can't be used. (This is clearer with custom objects where relationship fields end in `__r`.)

For the same reason, you will also have to query to get:

```
OLI.Product2.Name
```

though based on this [Product and Schedule Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm) ERD the relationship is via `PriceBookEntry`.